# javascript: switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to learn how to do a switch statement using javascript. Can you guys help me how to convert this one into switch statement?

```
        if (x == ix && y == iy){//should be the default 
            x.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; 
        }
        if(x < ix){
            x.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
        }
        else if(x > ix){
            x.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';  
        }
        if(y < iy){
            x.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
        }
        else if(y > iy){
            x.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';  
        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't rewrite this using a switch statement, and it isn't really possible either.  By the way if `x == ix` but `y != iy` then you may have a case which sort of falls through the cracks.  You should double check your logic.

Comment: have you made a little graphic about the result? the values of `y` have a higher priority over `x`.

Comment: What are `x`, `y`, `ix` and `iy` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why not ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not support operations other than strict equality in `switch`es. In other words, you cannot write that program as a `switch`.

In a `switch`, you can compare a variable to different values (or `case`s) and check if they are equal. If they are, you execute the code given under the `case`.

There is a drawback, however, and it is that you can convert this code into a switch easily:

```
if (a === 1) {
  console.log("one");
} else if (a === 2) {
  console.log("two");
} else {
  console.log("Out of range! :(");
}
```

The above code in `switch` is

```
switch (a) {
  case 1:
    console.log("one");
    break;

  case 2:
    console.log("two");
    break;

  default:
    console.log("Out of range! :(");
    break;
}
```

But you cannot do the same to a code that contains relational operations.

```
switch (a) {
  case > 1: // throws error
    doSomething();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Well... here's something that you might find surprising https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jpw147pr/

Comment: I see i came from php backend just trying if javascript can do such a php

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, that's interesting, but unfortunately, that's not what I mean here.

Comment: @KarthaCoder I get your point and I was just sharing an interesting piece of code ;) I'm actually not sure whether it should be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could be helpful to convert your above conditions.

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
}
```